# load angularjs module only if available

Tags: angularjs

I want to load my sub angularjs module only if it available, I am adding subApp module but if subApp not found then my mainApp module also stop working.

I have searched for this in stack overflow, but I did not get any perfect solution to my problem.

```
var mainkApp = angular.module('mainApp',['subApp']);
```

this is my code please give me a solution to my subApp module will load only if exist, thanks

Comment: You can try to load your sub-app using routes. In that case when user clicks a link you check if you have the sub-app in the location and do the logic based on that

Comment: In my case when I click a button one HTML content load inside to my mainApp at the same time new module also get loaded, so I want to combine that module with my main controller only when I click button, is it possible in routes

Comment: This feels like an XY problem.  why would you ever need to have a module that was only available some of the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load a module when it is needed by using ui-router's lazyLoad property on a state definition.

```
var mystate = {
  name: 'messages',
  url: '/messages',
  component: messages,
  lazyLoad: function() {
    return System.import('moment');
  }
}
```